# Store value of this.id as global variable for other functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables

How can I store the ID value of this button so that I can use it on another function  that won't get a click?

```
<button id="1" onclick="myfunction(this.id)">Click Here</button>

function myfunction(clicked){
var thisnum = clicked;
document.querySelector(".holder--" + thisnum).classlist.add("store")
}

function secondfunction(){
document.querySelector(".box--" + thisnum).classlist.remove("store")
}
```

Comment: a) with `var` inside the `myfunction`, it's not global b) where are you calling the `secondfunction`?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate variables outside of the function, and give them a value from inside the function like so:

```js
var thisnum; // Initiate the variable globally

function myfunction(clicked){
  thisnum = clicked; // And now change its value
  secondfunction();
}

function secondfunction(){
  console.log("Here is the id: " + thisnum); // And now read its value
}
```

```html
<button id="1" onclick="myfunction(this.id)">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and passes along the element id, but to answer your question - you need to initialize the variable outside of any functions. Then when you set it (in a function or elsewhere), it will be available to other functions in the script.

---

I thought I might help further your knowledge by showing a 'better' way to go about this.

The `onclick` in the button is an event listener, but the preferred way to do this is to attach the listener through javascript.

```
document.querySelector('#theButton').addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

You'll notice I put this in a `window.onload` function below. That is because we don't want to try and set the listener until all the HTML has had a chance to get on the page (after the page loads).

This listener function automatically passes along one function argument `event` which you can name anything (you'll often see it as `e`). The reference to the object that created this event (the button) is always `e.target`

Also passing attributes like numbers is best done through [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which are cool because you can put any information in those and easily pick them up in your script.

```
  <button data-id="1" id='theButton'>Click Here</button>
  <!-- notice the data-id attribute -->

  // and in your script:
  var thisnum = e.target.dataset.id
```

Plus, although technically you can do things like `id='1'` on an element, it's not good practice. It's better to use an explicit string (or at least start with a letter).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#theButton').addEventListener('click', myfunction);
}

let id // define the variable outside of the functions

function myfunction(e) {
  id = e.target.dataset.id // set the variable wherever
  console.log('the ID:', id);
  
  setTimeout(() => {otherfunction()}, 1000);
}

function otherfunction() {
console.log("ID from otherfunction: ", id)
}
```

```html
<button data-id="1" id='theButton'>Click Here</button>
```